# Stored Procedure issue which states Procedure: [dbo].[GetInfo] contains an unresolved reference to an object

Tags: sql, sql-server

Guys I really need your help. The problem is in Visual Studio I am trying to create stored procedure with an inner join of two tables: КатегорииЗатрат (in English means Category) and Расходы (in English means Expenses) in order to make sure that I could show name of Category instead of its id.

However, I get an error

> Procedure: [dbo].[GetInfo] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [dbo].[КатегорииЗатрат].[c]::[КатегорииЗатратId] or [dbo].[Расходы].[c]::[КатегорииЗатратId]`.

The code that I am using:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInfo]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        [Период],
        [Стоимость],
        [КатегорииЗатратId],
        [Комментарий]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Расходы] AS с 
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[КатегорииЗатрат] AS cat ON c.КатегорииЗатратId = cat.Id
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify which table you would like to select `[КатегорииЗатратId]` from. e.g.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInfo]

AS
Begin
    SELECT 
    [Период],
    [Стоимость],
    c.[КатегорииЗатратId],
    [Комментарий]
    FROM [dbo].[Расходы] as с inner join [dbo].[КатегорииЗатрат] as cat on 
    c.КатегорииЗатратId=cat.Id
End
```

Comment: Hi Nick thanks for your attention and reply, well I have done as you said, that is, I have added table prefix c.[КатегорииЗатратId], but that did not solve the problem it shows the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Your select contains a field reference which SQL Server cannot resolve since the field exists in more than one table in your select so it doesnt know which one you mean.

add the table prefix to each field in your select list.

Comment: @NickSpicer has it covered  ;)